# FulLCalendar 5: different colors for per event source don't show up in month view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have two event sources, configured like so:

```
this.eventSources = {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            color: '#228B22',
            textColor: '#000000',
            backgroundColor: '#90EE90',
            url: this.config.loadUrl,
            startParam: 'from',
            endParam: 'to',
            extraParams: {
                client_id: 0,
                agenda_item_type_id: 1
            }
        },
        2: {
            id: 2,
            color: '#0e64a0',
            textColor: '#000000',
            backgroundColor: '#87CEFA',
            url: this.config.loadUrl,
            startParam: 'from',
            endParam: 'to',
            extraParams: {
                client_id: 0,
                agenda_item_type_id: 2
            }
        }
    };
```

I set them before `calender.render()` like so:

```
Object.values(this.agendaItemTypes).forEach(itemType => {
    if (itemType.initiallyVisible) {
        this.calendar.addEventSource(this.eventSources[itemType.id]);
    }
});

this.calendar.render();
```

This works fine. After the initial render, only `initiallyVisible` events are displayed. Using checkboxes I can toggle visibility per event type, which almost works as expected. Only the colors don't show up as intended. Using the standard theme, the bullets in `dayGridMonth` view, are displayed in the configured `color`. Other than that, events are displayed in the default colors, seemingly ignoring the `textColor` and `backgroundColor` of the event source.

Did I miss something in the documentation or is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?